# Unable to make JDBC Connection - no solution that works :/

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I've got a problem with Maven / Spring project. I am trying to apply database from MySQL Workbench, but with no success.

Here are my files:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="shakira" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="myPass" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/shakira" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**HibernateTest.java**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.packt.webstore.domain.Product;


public class HibernateTest {
  private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
      Product product = new Product();
      product.setId(1);
      product.setName("Name");

      try {
         entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("shakira");
          EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
          entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
          entityManager.persist( product );
          entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
          System.out.println("successfull");
          entityManager.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.3.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.3</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>









    </dependencies>

    <resources>


        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>persistence.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**The error**

```
> 2017-02-14 23:34:43WARN  HibernatePersistence:58 - HHH015016:
> Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. 2017-02-14
> 23:34:43WARN  HibernatePersistence:58 - HHH015016: Encountered a
> deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
> [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
> [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. 2017-02-14
> 23:34:43INFO  LogHelper:31 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo
> [     name: shakira   ...] 2017-02-14 23:34:43INFO  Version:45 -
> HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.7.Final} 2017-02-14 23:34:43INFO 
> Environment:213 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 2017-02-14
> 23:34:43INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
> {5.0.1.Final} 2017-02-14 23:34:43WARN  pooling:70 - HHH10001002: Using
> Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
> 2017-02-14 23:34:43INFO  pooling:126 - HHH10001005: using driver
> [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/shakira]
> 2017-02-14 23:34:43INFO  pooling:135 - HHH10001001: Connection
> properties: {user=root, password=****} 2017-02-14 23:34:43INFO 
> pooling:140 - HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false 2017-02-14
> 23:34:43INFO  DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:41 - HHH000115:
> Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
> service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
>   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>   at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>   at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>   at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>   at
> org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
>   at
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>   at
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>   at HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:19) Caused by:
> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection
> [jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/shakira]  at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
>   at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>   at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>   at
> org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
>   ... 15 more
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.packt.webstore.domain;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

//import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
//import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
//import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import com.packt.webstore.validator.Category;
import com.packt.webstore.validator.ProductId;

//@XmlRootElement
@Entity
//@Table(name = "Produkty")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_produkt")
    private long id;

    @Pattern(regexp="P[0-9]+", message="{Pattern.Product.productId.validation}")
    @ProductId
    @Column(name="produkt_id_sklepowe")
    private String productId;

    @Size(min=4, max=50, message="{Size.Product.name.validation}")
    @Column(name="nazwa")
    private String name;

    @Min(value=0, message="Min.Product.unitPrice.validation}")
    @Digits(integer=8, fraction=2, message="{Digits.Product.unitPrice.validation}")
    @NotNull(message="{NotNull.Product.unitPrice.validation}")
    @Column(name="cena")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name="opis")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="producent")
    private String manufacturer;

    @Category(message = "{Category.Product.category.validation}")
    @Column(name="kategoria")
    private String category;

    @Column(name="ilosc_dostepnych_sztuk")
    private long unitsInStock;

    @Transient
    private long unitsInOrder;

    @Transient
    private boolean discontinued;

    @Transient
    private String condition;
    //@JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile productImage;
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile productPdf;

    public Product(){
        super();
    }

    public Product(String productId, String name, BigDecimal unitPrice){
        this.productId=productId;
        this.name=name;
        this.unitPrice=unitPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(this == obj)
            return true;

        if(obj==null)
            return false;

        if(getClass()!=obj.getClass())
            return false;

        Product other = (Product)obj;

        if(productId==null){
            if(other.productId != null)
                return false;
        }else if(!productId.equals(other.productId))
            return false;

        return true;    
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime*result + ((productId ==null)?0:productId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Produkt [productId="+productId +", nazwa=" + name+"]";
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public long getUnitsInStock() {
        return unitsInStock;
    }

    public void setUnitsInStock(long unitsInStock) {
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }

    public long getUnitsInOrder() {
        return unitsInOrder;
    }

    public void setUnitsInOrder(long unitsInOrder) {
        this.unitsInOrder = unitsInOrder;
    }

    public boolean isDiscontinued() {
        return discontinued;
    }

    public void setDiscontinued(boolean discontinued) {
        this.discontinued = discontinued;
    }

    public String getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    //@XmlTransient
    public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }

    public MultipartFile getProductPdf() {
        return productPdf;
    }

    public void setProductPdf(MultipartFile productPdf) {
        this.productPdf = productPdf;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I have found some solutions, but none have worked. Here is the list of what I've tried:

1. Changing provider to "ejb"
2. Changing versions of all hibernate dependencies
3. Changing port from 3306 to 8888
4. Turning off firewall
5. Changing my.ini file with commenting skip-networking line
6. I've also put the address inside the internet browser and i received a file with this inside:

   ```
     N   
     5.7.17-log #   ;#80&X ˙÷! ˙          IY
     me)q^* mysql_native_password !  ˙„#08S01Got packets out of order
   ```

Maybe that's the clue?

Thanks in advance for any help!

### **UPDATE**

I probably resolved it by adding hibernate.properties instead of persistence.xml (I have deleted all the  tags from persistence.xml inside of  tag)

Here is the file **hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.connection.autocommit=true


hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shakira
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=szczypi)rek13
hibernate.connection.pool_size=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the persistence unit by using the `HibernatePersistenceProvider`:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
...
PersistenceProvider provider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
entityManagerFactory = provider.createEntityManagerFactory(
   "shakira", null);
```

Just on the side, the second argument is a `Map of properties` that you want to override or add on top of the ones defined in the `persistence.xml`. In your case it would be fine to just pass `null` value.

**Update**

One more thing that you might consider is adding `flush()` just before commit:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist( product );
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
System.out.println("successfull");
entityManager.close();
```

Comment: Many thanks to you, it helped with a Provider problem. Unfortunately there is still problem with connection. There is still written an error:
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: 

Unable to create requested service 
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/shakira]

Comment: After adding that line with flush() the error: "Error while committing the transaction" - has gone, but there is still problem with this "Unexpected exception during isValid call." I have searched some solutions for that, but mainly people said that it's caused by the wrong version of hibernate-validator. I tried newer and older versions, but nothing helped.